# Фиксированное меню при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Добрый день всем.
Прошу помощи в довольно таки простом задании, но самостоятельно найти ответ не получается.

Я использую [фиксированное меню jq](http://www.jozefbutko.com/stickynavbar/), все отлично, все работает, но, мне нужно в меню по мимо текста использовать еще и картинки. По логике, я пытаюсь сделать так:

`<li>
<a href="#s1"><img src="img/menu1.png"><br>Программа</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#s2"><img src="img/menu2.png"><br>Поиск</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#s3"><img src="img/menu3.png"><br>Контакты</a>
</li>`

Использую обычный `<br>` что бы сделать текст под картинкой, все бы было хорошо, но меню начинает идти вертикально. Т.е. без картинок меню горизонтальное, как только начинаю писать `<br>` после каждой картинки - меню становится вертикальным.

Почему так происходит? я ведь использую для `<li>` `display: inline;`

Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте использовать float:left или display: inline-block;

Comment: Совсем забыл о display: inline-block. Спасибо вам огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Пример реализации фиксированного меню с иконками на jQuery

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

ul.menu li {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.menu img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.content {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Полный пример рабочего кода смотри тут: https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/qRGNWW